# Truncate date string into just year and week

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm using Luxon to manipulate `Date`s in my code. My method returns a date like this:

`DateTime.utc(1982, 5, 25).toISOWeekDate() //=> '1982-W21-2'`

I need to knock off the day part and have `'1982-W21'`instead.

Not too familiar with js, how would I "knock off" the day part..

Comment: That is not valid javascript. There is no `DateTime`

Comment: You could use the `split()` method. link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @Jamiec: Looks like [`Luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) to me.

Comment: @Jamiec Of course this is valid JavaScript. Using or not using a library doesn’t change the fact that this follows ECMAScript grammar.

Comment: Ok, it wasnt tagged Luxon when I originally commented, nor did it mention that library at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split, slice and join the result, or extract a substring like this:

```js
console.log('1982-W21-2'.split('-').slice(0, 2).join("-"));

// or
const dateResult = "1982-W21-2'"
console.log(dateResult.substr(0, dateResult.lastIndexOf("-")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Luxon, this method does not provide a formatter, so you need to do minor string manipulation.

This JavaScript will do:

```js
DateTime.utc(1982, 5, 25).toISOWeekDate().split('-').slice(0,2).join('-')
```

It first `split`s the string by `-` into an array (3 members), then creates (`slice`) a new array from the first two members, and then `join`s the two members by `-` again.